# Laravel 5 return view then redirect after

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

So, I have this function, how do i make it to return 2 views after time passed?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class emailverified extends Controller
{
  public  function emailverified()
    {
        return view('auth.email.emailverified');
        sleep(3);
        return redirect()->away('https://www.xxx.xxx');
    }
}
```

It only chose one or the other path. How do i make it return view then after the sleep timer return to another view?

Comment: you can add redirection in first view, which take user to the second view.

Comment: @Tera How do you expect `sleep(3)` to be executed when you are `return`ing from the script previously?.

Comment: @ako I expect it to show view, wait 3 sec and forward (it the view it says you will be redirected after 3 sec,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use javascript inside your controller function

```
class emailverified extends Controller
{
  public  function emailverified()
    {
        echo "<script>setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = 'https://www.xxx.xxx'; }, 3000);</script>";
        return view('auth.email.emailverified');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [header refresh](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#97114)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class emailverified extends Controller
{
  public  function emailverified()
    {
        return view('auth.email.emailverified')->withHeaders(['refresh' => '3;url=https://www.xxx.xxx']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and elegant ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its seems you are trying to show a response for the user and redirect to another page in a certain time interval, what you tried is wrong, once your code the return statement in a function, the script will not be further executed and your statement for redirect will not work..

Best solution is, Return the response as ajax response, and you can easily do both action in peralal,

```
$response = [      
    "ViewBag" =>   view('auth.email.emailverified')->render(),
    'URLTOREDIRECT' => 'https://www.xxx.xxx',
];
return response()->json($response);
```

Bind the following event to the button or anchor where you want the ajax call happen or if a form submission

```
$("#yourButtonId").live("click",function(event) {
           var url = '{!!  url("/your/path") !!}';
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",  //depending on your route is get or post
                url: url,
                data: $("#yourformid").serialize()+'&data1='+$('#data1').val()+'&data2='+$('#data2').val()',
                dataType : "json",
                beforeSend:   function(){
                    alert('loading'); //or your can show a user friendly loader
                }
            }).done(function(data) {

                $("#yourDivId").html(data.ViewBag);
                var delay = 1000;  //millisecond
                setTimeout(function(){ window.location = data.URLTOREDIRECT; }, delay);



            }).fail(function(data) {

                if(data.responseJSON){
                    var errors = data.responseJSON;

                    errorsHtml = '<ul>';
                    $.each( errors , function( key, value ) {
                        errorsHtml += '<li>' + value[0] + '</li>';
                    });

                    errorsHtml += '</ul>';

                  alert(errorsHtml);

                }else{
                    alert(data.responseText);
                }

            });

            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the view you can try `echo view('your view')`.

The code shouldn't be exited at that point

then add your sleep code and redirect, it should work i just tested it

Comment: `echo view('your view')` and then  `return redirect('view')`; solve my problem if you need to wait for a time use php wait method to stay on a page